# Precheck if the Connectors are Active in Logic-App before it Triggers

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a Logic App which listens to a Mailbox for a particular sender and other criteria.

Not often, but at random moments, we see our Logic App failed to trigger and the reason for such was connection being inactive.

Once we re-authenticate, and connection was turned to active it works smoothly, until the behavior happens again. So I am just curious to check from anybody how they handle such situation? Can we let know to another email that the connection is inactive.

Edit
[image]

Comment: May I know which connector/trigger did you use in your logic app and which email did you integrate in logic app ? O365 email ? Could you please provide more details of your logic app such as screenshots ? In my opinion, the connection would not be inactive automatically, it may affected by some change or some other reason.

Comment: HI @HuryShen I have attached a screenshot for this purpose. I am using o365 Connectors. Yes, it might be triggered for some reason, but if there is a way that it let us know beforehand that the connection requires re-authentication it would save us from near catastrophe.

Comment: Did you make any changes on the API Connection of your O365 ? And why do you use "When a new email arrives (V2)" trigger, I search the O365 connector and just find the V3 trigger. V2 trigger is deprecated now, is it the reason why you need to re-authenticate for the connection ?

Comment: I dont see V3 for me; Probably its not available for our Region. The only incident I can recall is we were added to Azure AD from On-Premise AD, but can that be a reason for such?